# Need Unity character controller to make sharp 90 degree turns and not slide when turning

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, momentum

I'm using the first person controller for my characters movement. On a left arrow keypress, I'd like the character to instantly rotate 90 degrees and keep moving forward. Currently, when I hit the arrow key, the character makes the sharp 90 degree turn, but the forward momentum the character previously had takes a second to wear off so the character ends up sliding in the direction he was previously moving a short bit.

The closest example I can think of to visually explain what I'm trying to do is how the character turns sharp in Temple Run. How my game is currently working, if I had the character on a ledge make a sharp left turn, he'd likely keep the original momentum and slide off the edge right after he turns.

Since my character is running on the x/z axis, I'm wondering if there would just be some way to maybe swap the directional velocity/momentum? The speed the character had on the x axis would instantly be switched to the z when it turns and the other would be set to zero. I'm obviously open to any solution that accomplishes what I'm looking for.

I dug into the CharacterMotor class in the first person controller, but have yet to find what part I can tweak to accomplish this.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to stop the velocity of the Rigidbody before turning.

```
this.rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
this.rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
```

If you want the object to continue like it did, you can try playing around with it by saving the current velocity in a variable, setting it to 0, rotate it and then putting back the old velocity (still forward).

If it works with global vectors (so from the point of view of the world, not the object), then you can try negativing the velocity, actually causing it to go 'backwards'. I can't test it for now but either way I think you need to set the velocity to zero first before turning the character.